# Batch script to delete files

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script as follows.

```
D:
del "D:\TEST\TEST1\Archive\*.TSV" 
del "D:\TEST\TEST1\Archive\*.TXT"
del "D:\TEST\TEST2\Archive\*.TSV" 
del "D:\TEST\TEST2\Archive\*.TXT"
del "D:\TEST\TEST 100%\Archive\*.TSV" 
del "D:\TEST\TEST 100%\Archive\*.TXT"
```

The above code deletes all the ".txt" and ".tsv" files from all the folders except from the folder `TEST 100%`. For deleting the files from `TEST 100%` i am getting the error as `The Path could not be found`. I guess the % symbol in the folder name creates the issue.
Can anyone guide me to resolve the issue and to delete the files from the folder `TEST 100%`?

Comment: Why do you have a quote on the first line?  Also, why are you referring to the drive when your batch file already changed to that drive with the first line?  I tried replicating your problem and everything worked.  Did you confirm that Archive exists in Test 100%?

Answer (score 128):

You need to escape the % with another...

```
del "D:\TEST\TEST 100%%\Archive*.TXT"
```

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but on my system there's no problem finding a path with %, and escaping with %% keeps the system from finding it.

Comment: @user1161318 - I did test it on Windows 7. Without the escape, in a batch file, results in "The system cannot find the path specified". As I posted it works.

Comment: Ok, on XP I get the opposite results.  It finds the path fine with %, but fails to find it with %%.

Comment: My guess is that you are doing it from the command prompt and not from a batch file.

Comment: You're probably right.  I keep forgetting that within a batch file, % is a variable prefix and you need to escape it. +1

Comment: System variables on CMD are %Like that%. For CMD scripting you should use %%that%% always.

Answer (score 13):

There's multiple ways of doing things in batch, so if escaping with a double percent `%%` isn't working for you, then you could try something like this:

```
set olddir=%CD%
cd /d "path of folder"
del "file name/ or *.txt etc..."
cd /d "%olddir%"
```

How this works:

`set olddir=%CD%` sets the variable `"olddir"` or any other variable name you like to the directory
your batch file was launched from.

`cd /d "path of folder"` changes the current directory the batch will be looking at. keep the 
quotations and change path of folder to which ever path you aiming for.

`del "file name/ or *.txt etc..."` will delete the file in the current directory your batch is looking at, just don't add a directory path before the file name and just have the full file name or, to delete multiple files with the same extension with `*.txt` or whatever extension you need.

`cd /d "%olddir%"` takes the variable saved with your old path and goes back to the directory you started the batch with, its not important if you don't want the batch going back to its previous directory path, and like stated before the variable name can be changed to whatever you wish by changing the `set olddir=%CD% line`.

Comment: This is best done through `pushd "folder" && del "filename" & popd`.

Answer (score 10):

Lets say you saved your software onto your desktop.
if you want to remove an entire folder like an uninstaller program you could use this.

```
cd C:\Users\User\Detsktop\
rd /s /q SOFTWARE
```

this will delete the entire folder called software and all of its files and subfolders

**Make Sure You Delete The Correct Folder Cause This Does Not Have A Yes / No Option**

Answer (score 4):

Consider that the files you need to delete have an extension `txt` and is located in the location `D:\My Folder`, then you could use the below code inside the bat file.

```
cd "D:\My Folder"
DEL *.txt
```

Answer (score -7):

in batch code your path should not contain any Space so pls change your folder name from "TEST 100%" to "TEST_100%" and your new code will be 
del "D:\TEST\TEST_100%\Archive*.TXT"

hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: Never heard of that. Is that new ? -Sarcasm off. It works with spaces as it does without, as long as you set it in quotation marks.