# .bat file that deletes 2 specific files on a specific directory

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

As the tile says. I need a .bat file to automatically delete 2 files on my C on a specific directory everytime I execute it.

I'm noob and don't know the commands :(

Comment: Do you know how to delete a single file from command prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to delete files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764103/batch-script-to-delete-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
del "C:\TEST\*.TXT"
```

For this example it will delete all files under `TEST` Folder with the `.TXT` extension so it depends on the extensions of the files , you can merely mention their names with their right extensions and it will work !

(Save the command in a `.bat` file and execute it as Administrator)